# Get just hour and minutes in Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0

I am totally new at Powershell and I need to get just hour and minutes in a script.

I currently have this:

[image]

Comment: You can find quite a lot of information if you use [Get-Help Get-Date -Full](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-3.0). Maybe it will even answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this `Get-Date -Format HH:mm`

Answer (score 10):

You almost have it; instead of `g`, use:

- `hh` for the hour in 12-hour format
- `HH` for the hour in 24-hour format
- `mm` for the minutes

For instance `Get-Date -Format hh:mm` will return the 12-hour time as "04:55", while `Get-Date -Format HH` will just return the hours in 24-hour time.

The full list of possible formats are at documented by Microsoft: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Powershell (Core) version 7 or higher, you can use the new `TimeOnly` data type. You can find more examples about this time in this [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/).

`$Time = [System.TimeOnly]::FromDateTime((Get-Date))`

`$Time.ToString()` prints `10:02`